# Float images randomly on screen objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I want to implement code for moving images randomly on screen in any direction. These images are also clickable ones. I have written code for 2 clickable images, but it is always starting from left corner and ending at one position. Here is the code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse |  UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.imageView.center.x,
                                                         self.imageView.center.y+100);
                                }
                 completion:NULL];
```

I have figured out the clickable part. Now I want to make the image float around the screen. I have tried varying the values inside CGPointMake but getting the same results. Please help to figure me out. Thanks.

Comment: Is this code in `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else. If `viewDidLoad`, try moving this code to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Yes, viewDidLoad worked. But now the animation is happening too fast. Even by changeing "animateWithDuration", I am not seeing any difference in the speed of animation. Can you help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following options

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                          delay:0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState |
                                 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut |
                                 UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{
       ...

        }];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        ...
    }];
```